# Laravel 5.4 Dingo/JWT API: Failed to authenticate for valid token

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, jwt, dingo-api

I've implemented Dingo REST API with Laravel 5.4. I'm able to fetch the token from the server. As well as the toke is successfully received by the server. But it is throwing 401 exception and this is the debug stack trace:

I've already tried to pass the token through url same results.

```
{
"message": "Failed to authenticate because of bad credentials or an invalid authorization header.",
"status_code": 401,
"debug": {
    "line": 113,
    "file": "C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Auth\\Auth.php",
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\UnauthorizedHttpException",
    "trace": [
        "#0 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Auth\\Auth.php(96): Dingo\\Api\\Auth\\Auth->throwUnauthorizedException(Array)",
        "#1 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\Auth.php(52): Dingo\\Api\\Auth\\Auth->authenticate(Array)",
        "#2 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(148): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Auth->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
        "#3 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#4 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\PrepareController.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#5 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(148): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\PrepareController->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
        "#6 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#7 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#8 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(576): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
        "#9 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(535): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#10 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(513): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#11 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Routing\\Adapter\\Laravel.php(81): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#12 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Routing\\Router.php(513): Dingo\\Api\\Routing\\Adapter\\Laravel->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), 'V1')",
        "#13 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\Request.php(126): Dingo\\Api\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#14 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(114): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#15 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#16 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
        "#17 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#18 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
        "#19 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#20 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
        "#21 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#22 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
        "#23 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#24 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\Request.php(127): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
        "#25 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\dingo\\api\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\Request.php(103): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Request))",
        "#26 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(148): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
        "#27 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
        "#28 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
        "#29 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(149): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
        "#30 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
        "#31 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\public\\index.php(54): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
        "#32 C:\\Users\\ghgf\\PhpstormProjects\\edwheel\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\Users\\\\ghgf\\\\P...')",
        "#33 {main}"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue long back. Actually while making request to Dingo API with Volley. We have to set the Content Type header to JSON.

Hope it helps someone.